# Rust accessing an object from multiple threads without using Arc/Mutex

Tags: asynchronous, rust, concurrency

I am trying to write a downloader in rust. The problem I am facing is that I am trying to implement a pausing function so a downloading method can be ongoing and another pausing method can be called to interrupt the downloading. Unfortunately using `Arc` and `Mutex` will not work since downloading will lock the object until the downloading progress is done.

Here is a minimal example:

```rust
struct Downloader {
    status : DownloadStatus,
    // some object storing download of file as bytes
}

impl Downloader{

    pub fn pause (self : &mut Downloader) -> () {
        self.status = DownloadStatus::Paused;
    }
    pub async fn download (self : &mut Downloader) -> () {
        self.status = DownloadStatus::Downloading;
        // mimic downloading of a file
        loop {
            match self.status {
                DownloadStatus::Paused => {break;},
                _ => {}
            }
            // downloading ..
        }
    }
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let downloader = Downloader {
        status: DownloadStatus::Idle
    };

    let download_task = tokio::spawn({
        async {
            // downloader.download().await;
        }
    });

    let pause_task = tokio::spawn({
        async {
            // tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await; // Simulating some delay
            // downloader.pause();
        }
    });

    // Await both tasks to complete
    let _ = tokio::try_join!(download_task, pause_task);
}
```

How to tackle such issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the structure in two parts.
An inner part contains all the members the downloading task needs, and an atomic boolean in order to influence this task from another thread.

All of this relies on **interior mutability**.
An atomic variable is by essence shared between multiple parallel tasks, but allows mutations.
The access to the inner part is protected by a mutex but since the atomic boolean is outside this inner part, both of them can be used simultaneously.
Thanks to this **interior mutability** and because all of this is actually shared, the methods only need a **shared reference** for `self`.

Please find below your example adapted accordingly.

Note that if an atomic boolean is not enough for the various states of the real problem, an [`atomic_enum` crate](https://crates.io/crates/atomic_enum) exists; it's probably better than relying on an atomic integer (without explicit semantics).

```rust
use std::{
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
        Arc, Mutex,
    },
    time::Duration,
};

struct InnerDownloader {
    amount: usize,
    // other members
    // ...
}
struct Downloader {
    downloading: AtomicBool,
    inner: Mutex<InnerDownloader>,
}

impl Downloader {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            downloading: AtomicBool::new(false),
            inner: Mutex::new(InnerDownloader { amount: 0 }),
        }
    }
    pub fn pause(&self) {
        self.downloading.store(false, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
    pub async fn download(&self) {
        self.downloading.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
        // mimic downloading of a file
        loop {
            if !self.downloading.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                break;
            }
            // simulating download
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(250)).await;
            if let Ok(mut inner) = self.inner.lock() {
                inner.amount += 1;
            }
        }
        println!("leaving download()");
    }
    pub fn amount(&self) -> Option<usize> {
        self.inner.lock().ok().map(|inner| inner.amount)
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let downloader = Arc::new(Downloader::new());

    let download_task = tokio::spawn({
        let downloader = Arc::clone(&downloader);
        async move {
            downloader.download().await;
        }
    });

    let pause_task = tokio::spawn({
        let downloader = Arc::clone(&downloader);
        async move {
            // Simulating some delay
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
            downloader.pause();
        }
    });

    // Await both tasks to complete
    let _ = tokio::try_join!(download_task, pause_task);
    println!("amount: {:?}", downloader.amount());
}
/*
leaving download()
amount: Some(8)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, interior mutability was the key.